# Creating filter pipelines for OpenCV

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS fans,

I'd like to use or develop a simple pipeline interface for sticking together various OpenCV filters.  As far as I can tell, the only package that currently works like this is ecto but it is a little more than I need right now so I was looking for a simple alternative.

I came across a [simple method](http://baoilleach.blogspot.com/2008/07/pipeline-python-generate-workflow.html) using Python that seems to get the job done.  For example, the following code glues together a grey_scale filter followed by Gaussian smoothing and histogram equalization.  The functions grey_scale, blur and equalize are defined in terms of standard OpenCV functions:

```
pipeline = create_pipeline((grey_scale,),
                           (blur, cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 15, 0, 7.0),
                           (equalize,))
```

where

```
def create_pipeline(self, *filters):
   def pipeline(frame):
       piped_frame = frame
       for filter in filters:
           piped_frame = filter[0](piped_frame, *filter[1:])
       return piped_frame
   return pipeline
```

I don't want to reinvent any wheels if someone has already developed something similar.  Is there anything like this out there other than ecto?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28481/creating-filter-pipelines-for-opencv/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://simplecv.org/ and [ecto](http://ecto.willowgarage.com/) would be your best bets I think

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-07-23**:
Thanks @Vincent.  I'm very impressed with Ecto to the extent that I have played with it.  I have also taken a quick look at simplecv and that looks nice too.